# Calling R function within Matlab and loading Matlab variables into the R function

Tags: r, matlab

I am calling R script from within Matlab. The R script is a function that should load the data generated from Matlab and then passes it through the R function, and finally computes a result and sends it back to Matlab. I have included a very simplified code below. The Matlab and R file are in the same path. The R_script.R is the following:

```
require("mclust")
group = function(data, num_cls){
    Mclustmodel = Mclust(data, num_cls)
    return(Mclustmodel$class)
}
```

In Matlab, the code is:

```
system( 'Rscript ./R_script.R' )
X = rand(10);
K = 3;
class = group(X, K);
```

*My question is: **Can I load `X` and `K` into the R function group, and directly calculate the answer?***

I am using a Linux system.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a package, R.matlab, that allows R to access Matlab as a server. I'm not seeing anything going the opposite direction other than the RDCOM interface which is a Windows only (and non-free) option

Comment: For the other way round, I would use http://www.rforge.net/JRI/

Comment: Right; forgot about RServe. And the place for support is the stats-rosuda-devel mailing list.

Comment: There is http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5051-matlab-r-link but it only works on Windows. You may try calling both R and Matlab from python - python has rpy2 for interfacting with R and pymatbridge for matlab.

Comment: you might just want to create your R to accept command line inputs and matlab to recieve outputs with `[status,cmdout] = system(command)`. instead of simply using variables, you'll have to stitch up strings though. i didn't have time to try it myself but seems possible

Comment: Sorry for bothering - was the code in the question itself a working example? Like - can you load a R function and call it from MATLAB like that? Or was it just the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [RMatlab](http://www.omegahat.org/RMatlab/). See [this](http://web.stanford.edu/~dgleich/notebook/2009/09/rmatlab_using_r_from_matlab.html) blog post for instructions. RMatlab is biderctional so you can run it from Matlab, send commands to R and get results as Matlab variables. It works on unix systems.